# Зачем при поиске максимального значения в массиве в Math.max.apply в качестве параметра прописывать null?

Tags: javascript

есть массив

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 4, 53]
```

Находим максимальное значение массива

```js
let max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
console.log(max)
```

Вопрос - зачем прописывать параметр null в Math.max.apply? Понятно, что без этого он работать не будет, но зачем?

Comment: Вызов apply нужен для передачи аргументов именно в виде массива. А null просто игнорирует this. Ничего это не меняет. Это обходные и запутывающие старые методы, нет смысла так делать вообще. `Math.max(...arr)` - и всего-то.

Answer (score 2):

Первый параметр метода [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) отвечает за значение, на которое будет ссылаться ключевое слово `this` внутри вызываемой функции.

В данном случае, внутри функции `this` не используется, поэтому первым параметром можно передать что угодно.